# Is there a way to input automatically when using cf passwd command?

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to use "cf passwd" to change cloud foundry user password automatically.

I've tried using:

```
printf '%s\n' "oldpasswd" "newpasswd" "newpasswd" | cf passwd test
```

But it still failed:

```
Current Password> stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

New Password> stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Verify Password> stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Changing password...
OK
```

Please help me to fix this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might give `uaac` a try, https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-uaac.  Docs on changing password using `uaac` are [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/uaa-user-management.html#changing-passwords).

Worst case, it would allow you to `uaac curl` the [API end point](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/api/uaa/#change-user-password) (password changes will go to UAA anyway) in which case you could change the password without needing inputs from STDIN.

As a side note, you can run `uaac -t <cmd>` or `CF_TRACE=true cf <cmd>` to see the API calls that the client is making on your behalf.  This is one of the easiest ways to figure out exactly how to use the CF APIs.